# devstack - how to reduce openstack keystone X-Subject-Token size

Tags: openstack-keystone

Through devstack I have installed openstack.

I issued following command to get token

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth": { "identity": { "methods": ["password"], "password": { "user": { "name": "admin", "domain": { "id": "default" }, "password": "test123" } } } } }' "http://localhost/identity/v3/auth/tokens" ; echo
```

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Fri, 04 May 2018 10:45:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

```
X-Subject-Token: gAAAAABa7DnIU_mCvOZ6voN53Ff41dzhTZd1k4-6aju6nVmgmjwgFYe5NioTK6mkCoRP29BIzwXcAMElFU1X9Pc119f16Y98fFMKzh14Rol4TEtLasxl5x4L7oKgnbLGXD-STMbq8MGq860B1a4xPAU0YyDsFu3ERw

Vary: X-Auth-Token
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 312
x-openstack-request-id: req-8a0cf0e2-70a1-40dd-8318-890ada890a64
Connection: close
```

How do i reduce X-Subject-Token size to 32 bit.

I have tried to reduce the size by setting max_token_size from lib/keystone config file by changing default value to 32 size

```
iniset $KEYSTONE_CONF DEFAULT max_token_size 16384
```

to

```
iniset $KEYSTONE_CONF DEFAULT max_token_size 32
```

After changing token size getting same token length.

Could anyone help me on how to reduce the size.

Thanks.